# Cannot convert django admin instance into and integer for math operations

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I'm quite new to python and I have django admin instances which I am getting from a queryset and I would like to convert them to integers so that I can apply math operations on them. An example is `person.height == Person.objects.get(height = 140)`. I want to use it as follows;

```
def getHeight():
    cm = 0
    if person.height == Person.objects.get(height = 140):
        cm = 1
    else:
        cm = 0
    return cm
```

Now when i do the following

`in_centimetres = getHeight()
 print(in_centimetres)
 print type(in_centimetres)`

I get the following as outputs:
`<persons.admin.operable instance at 0x7fac04bf29e0>`

and `<type 'instance'>`

I want to be able to get `0` or `1` so that I can perform math operations with that value.

Comment: Where did you write this method? Where does `person` come from?

Comment: Person is a model in the application. I wrote this method in admin.py as part of a custom  action

Comment: I am not talking about `Person` class but your `person` instance. Your code doesn't make sense as you didn't declare the `person` variable anywhere in the method nor you pass it as an argument.

Comment: yeah, I get it now. the `person` instance is in a for loop inside my admin action function. I did not add the `getHeight()` inside that function. I'll just try and fix it to check the result